# Should I pursue a M.S. in Mathematics or a Ph.D?

Tags: soft-question, career-development

I'm looking forward to any advices, but first of all, here's my story:

Right now I'm a freshman in high school.  I admit it, I love mathematics!  However, I suspect that I have ADHD and I can't really put any time and effort (no motivation) towards my homework and schoolwork.  I understand I should be able to survive through high school without a problem but this attitude obviously won't do me any good in college.  But for now let's just skip through this motivation about mathematics.

I want to major in mathematics because that's the only thing I'm good at.  Although I'm only a freshman, I accumulated enough credits that I can actually graduate the spring following the upcoming spring (so technically speaking, I'm a junior in high school).

My parents, however, are pushing me to either go for an M.D. or an M.B.A.  They said they won't *fund* my college education unless I agreed to pursue either of these degrees.  So, I'm planning to first get a B.S. in mathematics (obviously).  But I'm not sure if I want to get a M.S. or a Ph.D in mathematics, since I will pursue (probably) an M.B.A. after getting that graduate math degree.

Can anyone give me any ideas?  Appreciated!

Comment: Secondly, get exposure to a lot of subjects. Not mathematical subjects, but things like history, philosophy, etc. study a lot and see what you like. But if you are surely geared on going for math, you will question yourself several thousand times along the way whether you want to become a professor or work in industry. So I would briefly think about it, and put it off until my two last years of college.

Comment: It sounds like your parents may not realize there are many good job opportunities for math majors who have programming experience.  It's actually a very practical major, especially if you do applied math.  Also, if you have difficulties with motivation then med school will be torture, so I'd suggest avoiding that route.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not trying to be snide, or to make light of your medical condition (if you have one), but my initial reaction to your first paragraph is that there is a HUGE difference between being lazy and having ADHD. With due respect, what you are describing sounds like laziness. If you want to be a specialist in anything, math, medicine, whatever, then you are going to have to invest a huge amount of time and effort into achieving this. It is possible to do this even with ADHD or other related conditions.

Finally, you are so young that you shouldn't really try to completely determine your life path just yet. If you do that, your 10-year older self might be quite angry with you indeed. For now, simply pursue your interests with vigor and passion, whatever they are. When you go to college, see how you do in math. If you display good aptitude and really love it/put time into it, you might find that your parents are more receptive to your eventual goals, whatever they may be.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. I strongly agree that one needs not to lock himself into a career path too early - even if you're really good at high-school math, it's not an indication that you'll like or have aptitude for proofs. It's even less of an indication that research is something that's interesting to you.

Comment: You're right, I think I shouldn't think about it this early, but my parents are pushing me on it, thanks though!